# Error when running unit test with mock - "when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock"

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have looked at many SO questions and answers on this error and tried the solutions specified, but had no luck so far. So the issue is "when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock". I cant figure out what is wrong.Below is my test class :

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CustomerDaoConfigurationTest {

    private CustomerDaoConfiguration customerDaoConfiguration;

    private CustomerApiProperties properties;
    @Mock
    private ApiClientUtils apiClientUtilsMock;
    @MockBean
    private ApiClientTimeoutConfiguration apiClientTimeoutConfiguration;


    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        apiClientUtilsMock = new ApiClientUtils(new ApiClientTimeoutConfiguration());

        properties = new CustomerApiProperties();
        properties.setBaseUrl("MockBaseUrl");
        properties.setOauth(new OAuthProperties("token-url", "client-id", "client-secret"));

        customerDaoConfiguration = new CustomerDaoConfiguration(properties, apiClientUtilsMock, apiClientTimeoutConfiguration);

    }

    @Test
    void shouldCreateValidRestTemplateWhenPropertiesAreProvided() {

        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails clientCredentialsResourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setClientSecret("client-secret");
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setClientId("client-id");
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setTokenName("token-name");
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("token-url");

        OAuthProperties oauth = properties.getOauth();

        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
        messageConverters.add(new JsonApiHttpMessageConverter(new ResourceConverter(), new ObjectMapper()));

        when(apiClientUtilsMock.createClientCredentialsResourceDetails(oauth)).thenReturn(clientCredentialsResourceDetails);

        RestTemplate createdRestTemplate = customerDaoConfiguration.customerRestTemplate(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory(), messageConverters);

        assertThat(createdRestTemplate.getMessageConverters().size(), is(1));
        HttpMessageConverter<?> messageConverter = createdRestTemplate.getMessageConverters().get(0);
        assertThat(messageConverter, is(instanceOf(JsonApiHttpMessageConverter.class)));

    }
}
```

I get the exception on this line :

```
when(apiClientUtilsMock.createClientCredentialsResourceDetails(oauth)).thenReturn(clientCredentialsResourceDetails);
```

I am not mocking a final/prvate method.
The class I am testing is :

```
  @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Import(CustomerApiProperties.class)
    @Configuration
    public class CustomerDaoConfiguration {
    
        private final CustomerApiProperties properties;
        private final ApiClientUtils apiClientUtils;
        private final ApiClientTimeoutConfiguration apiClientTimeoutConfiguration;
    
    
        @Bean
        public RestTemplate customerRestTemplate(ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory, List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
            ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = apiClientUtils.createClientCredentialsResourceDetails(properties.getOauth());
            return new RestTemplateBuilder()
                    .requestFactory(() -> clientHttpRequestFactory)
                    .rootUri(properties.getBaseUrl())
                    .messageConverters(messageConverters)
                    .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(apiClientTimeoutConfiguration.getReadTimeout()))
                    .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(apiClientTimeoutConfiguration.getConnectTimeout()))
                    .configure(new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails));
        }
    }
```

And also

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class ApiClientUtils {

    private final ApiClientTimeoutConfiguration apiClientTimeoutConfiguration;

    public ClientCredentialsResourceDetails createClientCredentialsResourceDetails(OAuthProperties oauth) {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(oauth.getTokenUrl());
        resourceDetails.setClientId(oauth.getClientId());
        resourceDetails.setClientSecret(oauth.getClientSecret());
        return resourceDetails;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well ... The error message is very clear. You are not calling `when` on a mock method. You are calling it on a normal object method. Annotating a variable with `@Mock` will have Mockito create a mock object for you. But you are creating your own in the setup method. Remove that.

Comment: Well, it's not a mock: `apiClientUtilsMock = new ApiClientUtils(new ApiClientTimeoutConfiguration());` – you are assigning a regular instance and overwriting the reference to the injected `@Mock`. There's a dupe question

Comment: Also, you must not mix `@Mock` (Mockito) and `@MockBean` (Spring Boot). MockitoExtension does not know about `MockBean`